# Find Element id,name,Path for iOS app

Tags: appium, ios-app-group

I am using Appium for the automation of my iOS app. The problem is, iOS recorder is too slow which makes my script writing process slow. I can write the script manually but I need object/element name,id,xpath etc. Is there any free tool which can tell me the element id, name, Xpath of my iOS app?

-Vinay

Answer (score 1):

When you click on an element in the Appium inspector, you will get all that information (element ID, xpath, name etc.)

You wouldn't need to actually record the scripts to get that information, just launch the inspector and use the "screenshot" of you app to explore the elements and see how you can identify them.

You could also use the Accessibility Inspector in the iOS simulator to get some of the info that might help you identify the elements (accesibility ids, for example), there is more info on that here:

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html